# Micro SDHC card in Canon 500D

Tags: canon, microsd

Will a Micro SDHC card (& adapter) work in a Canon 500D? Any performance/quality issues? I tried with a card that I have, but it is a MicroSDXC (64Gb) and is not compatible with the 500D.

Comment: KenW - how did you find out the MIcroSDXC (64GB) was not compatible with the 500D? I have both (card yet to be opened) and was wondering.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason I can think of that it wouldn't work.  The cards are identical except for form factor.  Pins/circuits/protocols are the same though.  That said, unless you have a stock pile of SDHC cards lying around, it is generally cheaper to get fast full size cards than it is to get fast Micro cards.  If the reason is to be able to transfer them to a Micro based device, then you may want to consider an Eye-fi card that could do it wirelessly.

Comment: Many times the difference in folder structures/file systems between the camera and another mobile device will preclude being able to transfer images from the camera directly to the other mobile device via the microSD card.

Comment: @MichaelClark - any halfway decent phone can read it fine and anything fully DCIM compliant will be able to read the JPEGs pretty easily generally.  Maybe some devices won't work, but most of the devices I have that take a MicroSD card will read it no problem from one device to another.

Comment: Not all mobile devices are "halfway decent phones." Which is why Wi-Fi would probably be preferable to microSD as a transfer strategy.

Comment: Yes, but even my e-book reader can read folders.  iPhones don't have an SD Card slot at all and any Android device will work fine.  I don't know about Windows Phone, but I'd be shocked if you couldn't.  I'd expect Wifi to be far, far less likely to work than an sd-card, though it will work with iCrap devices.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am wanting to use the card in my 500D and my tablet (HP Envy) - microSD only. I will buy one and give it a try. WiFi transfer is a good idea, but I am trying to carry less when I am travelling.

Comment: @KenW - an Eye-Fi card doesn't require carrying anything extra.  It is just an SD card that goes in your camera and stays there, but it has an embedded wifi hotspot in it as well so that your computer can connect to it.